# Convert Html 5 img src data sting into Raw bytes or File

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, html

I would like to store the HTML 5 image src bytes into DB as binary or in a HardDisk. Later I want to read and assign it to img src="url"

Here is the HTML 5 code

`<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAOALMAAOazToeHh0tLS/7LZv/0jvb29t/
f3//Ub//ge8WSLf/rhf/3kdbW1mxsbP//mf///yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAAQAA4AAARe8L1Ekyky67
QZ1hLnjM5UUde0ECwLJoExKcppV0aCcGCmTIHEIUEqjgaORCMxIC6e0CcguWw6aFjsVMkkIr7g7
7ZKPJjPZqIyd7sJAgVGoEGv2xsBxqNgYPj/gAwXEQA7" width="16" height="14" alt="embedded folder icon">`

**How do I parse this and store it as raw bytes or images into DB/File?**

**Note:** The main reason for converting HTML 5 src bytes to DB/Harddisk image is, to generate the MS word 2007 format document which will embed those images.

Comment: yes. I removed my comment.

Comment: as have i...  should we go round-and-round deleting our comments about deleting our comments indefinitely??  :)

Answer (score 3):

*How do I parse this*

You can parse the data into a byte array using  [Convert.FromBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx).

As to how to store the data in SQL, for such a small image, you might as well just store it in the base-64 encoded form.  For larger images, you'll want to use a different method, but there are a myriad of answers there, and is probably better asked in a SQL forum.

Comment: Thanks! I got it. Still i need to remove those `image type` prefix etc. I am referring this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850866/unable-to-generate-png-image-from-html-5-canvas

Comment: I decided to store it in File system rather than DB :)

Comment: Yes - correct- you need to just execute FromBase64String on the data itself, which is the portion after the comma.  I overlooked mentioning this as it perhaps seemed obvious (to me) so my bad on that.

Answer (score 3):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // original source string
     string src = @"data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAOALMAAOazToeHh0tLS/7LZv/0jvb29t/ f3//Ub//ge8WSLf/rhf/3kdbW1mxsbP//mf///yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAAQAA4AAARe8L1Ekyky67 QZ1hLnjM5UUde0ECwLJoExKcppV0aCcGCmTIHEIUEqjgaORCMxIC6e0CcguWw6aFjsVMkkIr7g7 7ZKPJjPZqIyd7sJAgVGoEGv2xsBxqNgYPj/gAwXEQA7";

     // using regex replace to remove `data:image...` prefix
     string pattern = @"data:image/(gif|png|jpeg|jpg);base64,";
     string imgString = Regex.Replace(src, pattern, string.Empty);

     byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64CharArray(imgString.ToCharArray(), 0, imgString.Length);
     using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
     {
          Image image = Image.FromStream(ms);
          pictureBox1.Image = image;              
     }

     // write to file
     using(FileStream file = new FileStream("file.gif", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
     {
          file.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
     }
 }
```

and this is your image on form (just for example):
[image]